# How to read from .dzn file without variable names in Minizinc

Tags: minizinc

I'm new to Minizinc and I'm facing a problem. I have .dzn file that contains this

```
10 7
4
3 2
3 5
4 3
5 5
```

I wish to read this into my file with the first line `10 7` saved as `h=10` and `w=7`, the next line `4` saved as `n=4` and the last lines as an array `dims=[[3,2],[3,5],[4,3],[5,5]]`. I however have not found out how to do this as in the tutorials I have read the variables in the .dzn files are already named and can thus be easily called in the .mzn file, i.e. using the command `int: w;`. Is there any way to name the integers in the MiniZinc file instead without changing the .dzn file?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `dzn` file is not any file that contains data for a MiniZinc model. These files follow a strict format were all data is given in the form

```
<ident> = <expression>;
```

That is why your file is not a `dzn` file. Currently MiniZinc only support direct data in either the `dzn` format or the `json` format. Other formats can not be read by the compiler. The MiniZinc language currently does not have to capability to create a parser for custom data files.

If your data is only given in this format, then there are two options to use them with MiniZinc:

1. You can write a small script that transforms the format described into `json` or `dzn`. This could be done in any programming language.
2. You can use the MiniZinc Python scripting front-end: using Python you can parse the data and the MiniZinc module will allow you to directly assign the data to the instance.